# How To I have Text partially overlay my Image?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how to have a text partially overlaying an image.

**Screenshot:** → [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sttd.png). *(I have circled with blue what I want!)*

I have searched for this on Google, but the only result I received was [Image Captions](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-image-overlay-caption-using-css/), which is not what I am looking for.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have done research, the only thing that comes up is text **completely** overlaying the image, like a caption. That is not what I am looking for, if you saw the image.

Comment: Then you have to **demonstrate** what you have tried so we don't waste our time...we're not mind readers to *know* what you've tried and rejected. There are also **thousands** of questions right here on text and image overlays. Try doing a search.

Comment: There is my demonstration of what I am NOT looking for.

Comment: I've explained the minimum standards we expect here at SO...it's up to you now...help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use **`position: relative`** in your text element and offset it by some value to the left.

**Code:**

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  right: 6%;
}
```

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4m7cg5mq/).

**Example:**

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
#parent {
  width: 550px;
  height: 343px;
  background-image:
    url(https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/08/73/aa/76/trolltunga.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
}
#child {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  right: 6%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="parent">
    <h1 id="child">A Fantastic Title<br/>&rarr;</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```